# The symmetric product of elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $E$ is an elliptic curve, what is the symmetric product $F=E\times E/S^2$? It is a smooth surface, let $\pi\colon E\times E\to F$ be the projection, then we have $\pi^*K_{F}=K_E(-\Delta)=O_E(-\Delta)$ where $\Delta$ is the diagonal. Pushing forward the $1$-cycles we have $2K_F=-\pi_*\Delta$. So $K$ is not represented by an effective divisor, it has Kodaira dimension $-\infty$, it is a rational or ruled surface? Which one it is?

Comment: $F$ is geometrically ruled. The map $F\to E$ that sends $(x, y)$ to $x+y$ has $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ as its fibers.